# Can a Pokémon transform a human into a Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon

I've seen this clip from the Pokémon anime where a Malamar emits a bright light and turns Serena into a Braixen. That got me wondering: Is it possible for a human to be turned into a Pokémon by a Pokémon?

Comment: What show was it?

Comment: @SlightlyPsychotic - OP is likely referring to this nonsense; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1p5XFXaRnCQ

Comment: Short answer is *yes, it's happened a bunch of times;* https://screenrant.com/pokemon-lore-people-transform-ghost-types-yamask-phantump/

Comment: Does hypnotising a human so they think they're a Pokémon count? https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=waMw6t_7z6E https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNfLZFdPDik

Comment: This should *maybe* be on the Movies and TV SE, or the Anime and Manga SE.

Comment: @SlightlyPsychotic - Why? It's perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: @Valorum Just because the asker says the basis for the question is from an anime, and because people on the Anime/Manga SE will probably be more able to answer the question, considering Pokemon is more anime/manga, and people on that site will probably know more about it than people on this one.

Comment: @SlightlyPsychotic In my experience, Anime & Manga SE is far less active and (with the greatest of respect) has a far higher proportion of answers from low-rep users who don't know what they're talking about. You're far more likely to get answers here than there. (Even if that wasn't the case, you should note that this question has already received two perfectly good answers, so the matter of whether other SE sites would also know the answer is, on this occasion, completely moot IMHO.)

Answer (score 12):

Many examples of Pokémon transforming humans into Pokémon are from the spin off series Pokémon Mystery Dungeon (quoting [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Human)):

> - In Pokémon Mystery Dungeon: Red Rescue Team and Blue Rescue Team, a greedy Trainer grabbed a tail of a Ninetales. The resulting curse was taken by his Gardevoir, and the Ninetales prophesied that the human would be reincarnated as a Pokémon in the future during a time of natural disasters. The player is summoned to the Pokémon world by that Gardevoir to stop a falling star from destroying the world, losing their memory in the process.
> - In Pokémon Mystery Dungeon: Explorers of Time, Explorers of Darkness, and Explorers of Sky, the player and Grovyle were trying to solve the mystery of the paralyzed planet and traveled to the past. There, they were separated when Darkrai attacked them, and the player was turned into a Pokémon. Having lost their memory, the player washes up on the Beach and is found by their partner.
> - In Pokémon Mystery Dungeon: Gates to Infinity, many humans have been summoned from an alternate dimension to the Pokémon world by Hydreigon, the Voice of Life, to save the world from the Bittercold. However, all of them were defeated by Munna and her gang and sent back to the human world. The player was then summoned, the only human left to save the Pokémon world.
> - In Pokémon Super Mystery Dungeon, Dark Matter once attempted to attack the Tree of Life, which would have caused the planet to crash into the sun, but was defeated due to the efforts of a human and Mew. However, they failed to completely destroy Dark Matter, so the player is brought from an alternate dimension to the Pokémon world by Mew to save the world when Dark Matter begins to rise again. Finding they have lost their memory, the player meets Nuzleaf and their partner.

Additionally, the ending of several of these involves:

> The player having to return to the human world, but their partner Pokémon makes a wish for them to remain in their world as a Pokémon, which happens.

Answer (score 5):

Since you didn't specify a particular continuity, the *[Detective Pikachu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detective_Pikachu_(film))* film has two such transformations.

> Howard reveals himself as the true mastermind behind the "R" gas and the Mewtwo experiments. He explains that Mewtwo can fuse humans with their Pokémon, but only if the Pokémon is in a crazed state, thus necessitating the need for R. Howard uses a device to transfer his consciousness into Mewtwo, unleashes the gas on the city from parade balloons and starts fusing humans with Pokémon, including Lucy and Yoshida....

....

> Mewtwo explains that Harry had tried to save him from Howard and helped Mewtwo escape, but was attacked by the Greninja. Mewtwo then decided to heal Harry's wounded body, which was when Pikachu volunteered to have his consciousness fused with Harry's in order to continue their investigation, and as a result, the experience erased both Harry's and Pikachu's memories. Mewtwo separates the two, and Tim reunites with his father in his human body. Tim then decides to stay in Ryme City to become a detective and spend more time with his father, Pikachu, and Pokémon.

Whether that is the case in [the video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detective_Pikachu_(video_game)) is ambiguous, although [the sequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detective_Pikachu_Returns) clarified that Harry's consciousness was placed in Pikachu while his unconscious body remained inert (with the consciousness and memories largely locked away to prevent Pikachu's consciousness being overwritten), and also features the villain taking over Deoxys's body.

Comment: The sequel's out already.

Comment: Updated with information from the sequel game.